# python reload function and syntactically incorrect module

Tags: python

What happens when I reload a module in python and the new code for the module is syntactically incorrect? The reload(module) function doesn't seem  to be throwing any exception. Is there any way to determine if the reload was successful or failed?

Comment: when you say "reload", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I meant reload(module) built-in function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reload() command should raise a SyntaxError:

```
In [34]: import test
# This works fine
```

After making a syntax error in test.py:  (changed import --> pimport)

```
In [35]: reload(test)
------------------------------------------------------------
   File "/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py", line 2
     pimport itertools
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Thanx a lot. I think I figured out my mistake. I had introduced a a simple syntax error in the middle of a function. That error didn't really stop python from reloading the module. Since I was editing in Eclipse with PyDev it showed me the error in advance and I was wondering why Python is allowing to reload the module.